# ¿Existe alguna forma de probar Layers de manera offline en Python con Serverless?

Tags: python, aws, serverless

Estoy intentando usar **Lambda Layers**en mi proyecto de **Python con Serverless** de manera offline, para poder hacer pruebas, osea, necesito probar las layers de manera local. Hasta el momento no he podido encontrar una manera de hacerlo, las que he intentado no me sirven.

**¿Alguien sabe de una forma en la qué pueda probar las Layers de manera offline o local?**

Intenté guiarme de una respuesta que encontré en:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55590156/serverless-offline-undefined-module-when-loaded-from-lambda-layer/55606906#55606906

Sin embargo no me funciona :c

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado localmente lambdas con Python pero te recomendaria revisar si te es util usar localstack que puede emular varios servicios de manera local y todos son configurables.

https://docs.localstack.cloud/overview/

https://pypi.org/project/localstack/

https://medium.com/uk-hydrographic-office/lambda-layers-in-localstack-the-free-version-a48c1228176

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/400902)

Answer (score -1):

Lo que puedes hacer es descargarte el código de la capa por un lado y configurar  el entorno para que tu aplicación busque código python en la ruta donde has descargado el código de la capa